# Oracle rank a chronological range of records based on a condition

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands, oracle12.2

Let's say I have a table containing some GPS points with their speed attribute
(let's ignore position here):

```
ID   TIME                 SPEED   
--------------------------------- 
 1   2024-01-01 09:00:02     0
 3   2024-01-01 09:00:03     0     
 6   2024-01-01 09:00:04     2
 8   2024-01-01 09:00:09    11
14   2024-01-01 09:00:10    15
11   2024-01-01 09:00:22    22
12   2024-01-01 09:00:28     4
10   2024-01-01 09:00:32     0
15   2024-01-01 09:00:33     2
16   2024-01-01 09:00:34     8
17   2024-01-01 09:00:35    12
18   2024-01-01 09:00:38    3
```

I need to uniquely identify the **ranges** of records for which the **speed** was **< 5**, keeping the `TIME` sorting.

Something like this (I included 2 valid alternatives: RANGE_NO and ALT_RANGE_NO):

```
ID   TIME                 SPEED   RANGE_NO     ALT_RANGE_NO
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
 1   2024-01-01 09:00:02     0    1                   1
 3   2024-01-01 09:00:03     0    1                   1
 6   2024-01-01 09:00:04     2    1                   1 
 8   2024-01-01 09:00:09    11    (null or 0)         2
14   2024-01-01 09:00:10    15    (null or 0)         2 
11   2024-01-01 09:00:22    22    (null or 0)         2 
12   2024-01-01 09:00:28     4    2                   3
10   2024-01-01 09:00:32     0    2                   3
15   2024-01-01 09:00:33     2    2                   3 
16   2024-01-01 09:00:34     8    (null or 0)         4
17   2024-01-01 09:00:35    12    (null or 0)         4
18   2024-01-01 09:00:38     3    3                   5
```

I'm trying with analytical functions, but I couldn't manage to RANK on such a condition keeping the order by `TIME` (or a numeric equivalent obtained by `RANK() over(order by TIME)`).
Sure I can identify the "edge" points using `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functions to get when the next or previous record exceeded the speed threshold.
But I can not figure out a suitable `partition by` condition.
I always find that if such a condition existed it would be the same "RANGE_NO" that I'm looking for.

Can I obtain this classification in a single query or with (a few) subqueries or `with` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a kind of *gaps and islands* problem, you can create your groupings by counting when the speed changes to more than 5 using window function `LAG()`, like so:

```
SELECT  ID, TIME, SPEED,
   1+ SUM(CASE WHEN minSpeed = prevSpeed THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
      OVER (ORDER BY TIME) ALT_RANGE_NO
FROM (
  SELECT ID, TIME, SPEED, minSpeed, Lag(minSpeed, 1, minSpeed) over(ORDER BY TIME)  prevSpeed
  FROM (
    SELECT ID, TIME, SPEED, CASE WHEN SPEED < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as minSpeed
    FROM mytable
  )
  ORDER BY TIME
)
```

Results :

```
ID  TIME                       SPEED    ALT_RANGE_NO
1   01-JAN-24 09.00.02.000000   0       1
3   01-JAN-24 09.00.03.000000   0       1
6   01-JAN-24 09.00.04.000000   2       1
8   01-JAN-24 09.00.09.000000   11      2
14  01-JAN-24 09.00.10.000000   15      2
11  01-JAN-24 09.00.22.000000   22      2
12  01-JAN-24 09.00.28.000000   4       3
10  01-JAN-24 09.00.32.000000   0       3
15  01-JAN-24 09.00.33.000000   2       3
16  01-JAN-24 09.00.34.000000   8       4
17  01-JAN-24 09.00.35.000000   12      4
18  01-JAN-24 09.00.38.000000   3       5
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/y2nPxQ4g)